# sqlite file does not fill the tableView - it works with simple data though - ? (sqlite, core data, pre-populate data)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, sqlite, persistent-storage

i have a well pre-populated sqlite file that i copied into my project (in the folder, and into the xcode project window)

when i check the sqlite file with the Terminal, it works fine, my sqlite file has the right data in it.

But then i try to fill my tableView with the data from the sqlite file, but the tableView is still empty.

Can you please tell me where i should look at?

i first tried with some data and it works (what is commented in applicationDidFinish...), but with my sqlite file, it does not work :

here's my code : (and here's the tutorial url : http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    /*
    THIS WORKS :
    FailedBankInfo *failedBankInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FailedBankInfo" 
                                                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
    failedBankInfo.name = @"the name";
    failedBankInfo.city = @"the city";
    failedBankInfo.state = @"the state";

    FailedBankDetails *failedBankDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FailedBankDetails"
                                                                         inManagedObjectContext:context];

    failedBankDetails.closeDate = [NSDate date];
    failedBankDetails.updatedDate = [NSDate date];
    failedBankDetails.zip = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12345];

    failedBankInfo.details = failedBankDetails;
    failedBankDetails.info = failedBankInfo;

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"%@,", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo" 
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (FailedBankInfo *info in fetchedObjects){
        NSLog(@"name : %@", info.name);
        FailedBankDetails *details = info.details;
        NSLog(@"zip : %@", details.zip);
    }
    [fetchRequest release];*/

    FailedBanksListViewController *root = (FailedBanksListViewController *)[_navController topViewController];
    root.context = [self managedObjectContext];
    [window addSubview:_navController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

/** Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"FailedBanksCD.sqlite"];
    /*NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] 
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"FailedBanksCD.sqlite"];
    */
     //NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];

    // Put down default db if it doesn't already exist
    NSString *storePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", storeURL];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                      pathForResource:@"FailedBanksCD" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
        }
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks as if the database was not copied to the doc-dir. Can you move this part

```
if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}
```

beyond this if block:

```
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
    ...
}
```

You have to remove the current empty DB from the doc-dir before trying again (remove in simulator, delete app from device and re-install).

Comment: thanks ott--, this does not refresh the table view unfortunatly. If i check what contains the copied sqlite from the doc-dir with `select * from ZFAILEDBANKINFO limit 3` it does not show me anything in the Terminal, maybe this is because it's encrypted. By any chance, could you have a look to my code? i have put the zip file containing the sqlite and the xcode project at : www.pondb.com (my personal website).

Comment: Are you working on the wrong DB? The data you're trying to extract are in banklist.sqlite3, while you copied the DB FailedBanksCD.sqlite.

Comment: thanks ott--, i think i mixed it up when i copied the failedbank sqlite file, it must be that because i tried again and again, and finally it works. Thanks for your help, Cheers